# UITableview not selecting cells through willdisplaycell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to preselect cells in a tableview by loading a list of numbers corresponding to the cells they've clicked in the passed. I load this from nsuserdefaults and use the willdisplaycell method to click on the cells. I've included my tableviewcontroller class that I use to do this.

```
@implementation AllergenTableViewController

static NSMutableArray *data;

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        data = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"DictKey"] allKeys] mutableCopy];
        self.allergens = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
     self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    //first need to load in array to a number list, then convert it to index path list and set allergens equal to that
    NSMutableArray *allergenNumberList;

    allergenNumberList = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"allergens"] mutableCopy];

    if (allergenNumberList != nil)
    {
        for (NSNumber *num in allergenNumberList)
        {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:num.integerValue inSection:1]; //[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:num.integerValue];

            if (![self.allergens containsObject:path])
            {
                [self.allergens addObject:path];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"loading view, allergens size: %lu", [self.allergens count]);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.allergens containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
    }
}

....

// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"allergenslabel"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"allergenslabel"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSIndexPath *idx in self.allergens)
    {
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:idx]];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"allergens"];
    NSLog(@"saving");
    NSLog(@"allergens count: %lu", [self.allergens count]);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //contains isnt working because the index pths arent the same but have the same row numbers so check those instead
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        if ([self.allergens containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [self.allergens removeObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        if (![self.allergens containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [self.allergens addObject:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"adding object");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"object already in allergens list");
        }
    }
}

@end
```

The problem is that when I go back in the navigation controller and move forward to the tableview again, the rows arent selected, but if I move forward in the nav controller and go back they'll be selected by default (I don't have to do anything for this to be true).

Update:

I went through and excluded some generic methods that weren't really relevant.

Comment: Can you put the breakpoint on        data = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"DictKey"] allKeys] mutableCopy];  line. when you go back in the navigation controller and move forward to the tableview again. and also update the code for pushing Table VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It turns out that there was something wrong with my comparison of NSIndexPath's or conversion of path to number. I added wrappers for checking containment inside my allergens array, (not using NSMutableArray's containsObject: method and by extension NSIndexPath's isEqual method and instead using a row comparison) and now the problem seems to be fixed. willDisplayCell: is being called and my cells are being checked off when the tableview first loads.

Answer (score 1):

When you go back in the navigation controller the view controller is released and thus the data on which row is selected is lost. Navigating forward to this page will instantiate a new instance of the view controller. Thats no longer the same table you saw before. When you go forward (throwing a new view controller on the stack) in the navigation the view controller with the table is retained in the navigation stack thus the data still exists as you left it. You will need find someplace else to save the data and pass it to this new instance.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I'm saving the data to NSUSERDEFAULTS and loading it from there upon initialization, I then load it into the tableview.  I was told that "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
" would automatically be called so that's where I set the selected cells and check if theyre inside my array

Comment: It's curious you are using initWithCoder for uiviewcontroller. Are you sure that method is being called? Is there a reason you don't want to do that in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yea I logged it, and honestly I didn't really think about it I'm new to IOS dev.

Comment: Do you make it all the way to [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO]; the second time around and its still not highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

The @Andrew McKinley's answer is completely right, so offering a solution, you can use a singleton to save your selected cells.

File > New > File > Cocoa Class > Class: Singleton Subclass: NSObject

```
// Singleton.h    

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject
+ (Singleton *)shared;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allergens;
@end
```

---

```
// Singleton.m

#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (Singleton*)shared
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if( sharedInstance == nil )
        {
            sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.allergens = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now you just need to import a Singleton.h to your AllergenTableViewController class and call the allergens array like:

```
[[Singleton shared].allergens addObject:@"obj"];
```

What is Singleton? *"In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system."* [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)